# Removing the 'prohibited' icon effect in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to remove all possible interactions between my user and my textarea. However, it's still possible to drag text, even though the cursor shows the 'prohibited' symbol. I would like to completely remove this interaction, so to speak.

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
#text-main {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    resize: none;

    margin: 10px;

    height: 475px;
    width: 675px;

    border: none;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#text-main::selection {
    background-color:transparent;
}

#text-main:hover {
    cursor:default;
}

#text-main:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#text-main::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1.5em;
}

#text-main::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #1F1F1F;
}

#text-main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 3px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text-main" name="text-main" tabindex="-1" readonly disabled>
```

Comment: just add `pointer-events: none` on your `textarea`. Apart that what you are facing is default browser behavior unfortunately we can't change this on our own. And this is not some `html`, `css` or `js` issue.

Comment: With some CSS trick you can put a **DIV** transparent over the textarea. 